# Compass Columns not showing beyond first row

Tags: compass-sass, multiple-columns, compass

I am using Compass Columns in a Drupal framework to create a grid for my content, with 5 columns in each row. However any content beyond the first five columns/listed items do not display at all, so I only have one row of columns showing even though I have 16+ listed items.

My code:

```
.product-item-list {
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            @include column-count(5);
        }
        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin-bottom: 2em;
            @include column-break(before, always);
        }
    }
```

Has anyone else come across this issue? Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @include column-break(before, always); and add add display-inline to the first div inside the li